# PHP Найти значение в файле и удалить строки

Tags: php

Пытаюсь упростить задачу по удалению инфы из конфига. В конфиге есть записи типа -

```
### Лицевой счёт - №****
class "*********" { match if binary-to-ascii(**, *, ":", suffix(option agent.remote-id, *)) = "**:**:**:**:**" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", substring(option agent.circuit-id, *, *)) = "***" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", suffix(option agent.circuit-id, *)) = "**";}
pool { range ***.***.***.***; allow members of "******";}

### Лицевой счёт - №****
class "*********" { match if binary-to-ascii(**, *, ":", suffix(option agent.remote-id, *)) = "**:**:**:**:**" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", substring(option agent.circuit-id, *, *)) = "***" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", suffix(option agent.circuit-id, *)) = "**";}
pool { range ***.***.***.***; allow members of "******";}

### Лицевой счёт - №****
class "*********" { match if binary-to-ascii(**, *, ":", suffix(option agent.remote-id, *)) = "**:**:**:**:**" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", substring(option agent.circuit-id, *, *)) = "***" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", suffix(option agent.circuit-id, *)) = "**";}
pool { range ***.***.***.***; allow members of "******";}
```

Задача найти  запись "### Лицевой счёт - №****" и удалить эту запись и 2 строчки после нее

Мой код:

```
$file = 'v309.conf';
$searchfor = '### Лицевой счёт - №3187';

$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Найдено:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "Записи не найдено!";
}
```

Как я могу это сделать?

Или, как удалить все строчки, включая искомую строку до следующей строки до "###..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file = __DIR__ . '/v309.conf';
$searchfor = '### Лицевой счёт - №3187';

$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$blocks = array_filter(preg_split('~^(?=###)~m', $contents));
$delete = preg_grep("~$searchfor\b~", $blocks);

if ($delete) {
    $new = array_diff($blocks, $delete);
    file_put_contents($file, $new);
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, возникла проблема с удалением.. Например, есть номер лицевого 2041 и 20419 - скрипт удаляет оба значения, а это чревато... Как пофиксить, чтобы скрипт искал только конкретное значение ?

Comment: @SyntaxWEB6stPRODWowSuite попробуйте заменить шаблон на вот этот вариант: `"~$searchfor\b~"`

Answer (score 1):

Давайте начнем с простого и с наиболее простых вариантов.
По вашему тексту видно, что та строчка которую надо удалить всегда начинается с `### Лицевой счёт - №`, этого достаточно, можно обойтись без регулярок:

```
$contents = '### Лицевой счёт - №****
class "*********" { match if binary-to-ascii(**, *, ":", suffix(option agent.remote-id, *)) = "**:**:**:**:**" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", substring(option agent.circuit-id, *, *)) = "***" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", suffix(option agent.circuit-id, *)) = "**";}
pool { range ***.***.***.***; allow members of "******";}

### Лицевой счёт - №****
class "*********" { match if binary-to-ascii(**, *, ":", suffix(option agent.remote-id, *)) = "**:**:**:**:**" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", substring(option agent.circuit-id, *, *)) = "***" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", suffix(option agent.circuit-id, *)) = "**";}
pool { range ***.***.***.***; allow members of "******";}

### Лицевой счёт - №****
class "*********" { match if binary-to-ascii(**, *, ":", suffix(option agent.remote-id, *)) = "**:**:**:**:**" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", substring(option agent.circuit-id, *, *)) = "***" and binary-to-ascii(**, *, "", suffix(option agent.circuit-id, *)) = "**";}
pool { range ***.***.***.***; allow members of "******";}';

$new_contents = '';
$count = -1;
$contents = explode(PHP_EOL, $contents);
foreach ($contents as $key => $value) {
    if (mb_substr($value, 0, 20) == '### Лицевой счёт - №') {
        $count = 0;
    }
    if ($count == -1) {
        $new_contents[] = $value;
    } else {
        $count++;
        if ($count == 3) { // сколько строчек суммарно удаляем
            $count = -1;
        }
    }
}
$new_contents = implode(PHP_EOL, $new_contents);
var_dump($new_contents);
```

Comment: Сделал вывод echo "<textarea>".$new_contents."</textarea>";, но искомая строка все равно там присутствует(

Comment: так же я заметил в условии mb_substr($value, 0, 20...  Дело в том, что лицевые могут быть от одного до пяти значений

Comment: @SyntaxWEB6stPRODWowSuite покажите конкретный пример (текст). по поводу второго вашего комментария - это не важно сколько там значений, хоть 30

Comment: Мне помог ответ Эдуарда, только проблема в том, что есть номер лицевого 2041 и 20419 - скрипт удаляет оба значения, а это чревато...